# Can I use a trigger to update a value in a table using criteria from another row?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that shows player's ranks after a two-player game. Table looks like:

| Player | Rank | Previous_rank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 954 | 977 |
| B | 1023 | 1000 |
| C | 1005 | 1015 |

I'd like to create a fourth column whose values get updated after each row entry based on who is playing whom

So if player A is playing player c next, I'd like the values to show

| Player | Rank | Previous_rank | opponent_rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 954 | 977 | 1015 |
| B | 1023 | 1000 | irrelevant |
| C | 1005 | 1015 | 977 |

I've tried the below trigger, which doesn't work, and also doesn't allow any additional entries to my tables

```
CREATE TRIGGER opp_rank_update 
BEFORE INSERT INTO stats
FOR EACH ROW

UPDATE rank
SET opponent_rank = SELECT (SELECT previous_rank FROM rank WHERE player = new.winner)
WHERE player = new.loser
```

This trigger is referencing another table that has raw data:

| Winner | W_Score | Loser | L_Score |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 21 | B | 18 |
| B | 21 | C | 15 |
| A | 21 | C | 16 |

Comment: there is an easy solution for 3 players, though what happens when you have more than 3 players and all ranks get updated?

Comment: i'm aiming to only update the two players' rows with their respective opponents' current rank. wouldn't need any calculations, just "looking up" the other players' rank

Comment: A view may be a better solution than a trigger.

Comment: @Shadow you're certainly not wrong. I'm just starting to learn by doing and figuring out the "right ways" vs. brute forcing things. appreciate the suggestion and will likely for the view route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using the following query:

```
WITH cte AS(
    SELECT *, 0+`Rank` - `Previous_rank`   AS diff
    FROM tab
)
SELECT t1.`Player`,
       t1.`Rank`,
       t1.`Previous_rank`,
       COALESCE(t2.`Rank`, 'irrelevant') AS opponent_rank
FROM      cte t1
LEFT JOIN cte t2
       ON t1.player <> t2.player
      AND t1.diff < 0 
      AND t2.diff < 0
ORDER BY t1.Player
```

The subquery (common table expression - cte) extracts the difference between the ranks, then we can apply a self join to the result of the previous query to match the players with negative difference.

For three players, this will work just fine.

Try it [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gp6ihjL6XboDskLhaFX6Ef/0).

Comment: thanks for answering and definitely understand your point now about working fine with 3 players. i kind of have a workaround at the moment where i insert data into table a, which updates table b, which then re-updates table a. pretty convoluted i'll admit but i'm too deep to take a step back and re-organize haha. since you technically got to the end result, will mark this as the answer